# Static route multi-hop priority (weight) in Bird2

Tags: networking, routing

I using BIRD2 to manage some static routes tables below.

And I want to set the IP go gateway to `10.13.0.1` via vpn3 first.

So I set weight to 3 and another 2 gateways set to 2 and 1.

But now the traffic always go through `10.12.0.1`,which one I set weight = 2.

The latency: vpn3 = vpn1 > vpn2

Seems weight not working.How to set only use `vpn3` gateway,and when it down then switch to others?

Static route tables:

```
route 15.235.0.0/16
via 10.13.0.1 % 'vpn3' bfd weight 3
via 10.12.0.1 % 'vpn2' bfd weight 2
via 10.11.0.1 % 'vpn1' bfd weight 1;
```

The latency: vpn3 = vpn1 > vpn2

```
protocol ospf v2 Out {
tick 2;
rfc1583compat yes;
ipv4 {
    import filter Block_All;
    export filter Block_All;
};
area 0 {
    interface "vpn1" {
        authentication none;
        check link;
        type ptmp;
        hello 10;
        retransmit 6;
        cost 30;
        transmit delay 5;
        dead count 5;
        wait 50;
        bfd;
        neighbors {
            10.11.0.1;
        };
    };

    interface "vpn2" {
        authentication none;
        check link;
        type ptmp;
        hello 10;
        retransmit 6;
        cost 20;
        transmit delay 5;
        dead count 5;
        wait 50;
        bfd;
        neighbors {
            10.12.0.1;
        };
    };

    interface "vpn3" {
        authentication none;
        check link;
        type ptmp;
        hello 10;
        retransmit 6;
        cost 10;
        transmit delay 5;
        dead count 5;
        wait 50;
        bfd;
        neighbors {
            10.13.0.1;
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Weights aren't priorities the way you want them – *metric* is. All nexthops in a single route are considered "**equal cost** multipath", with all options being available and weights only adjusting the relative chance that each nexthop will be selected.

In your example, the OS is selecting randomly from:

> vpn3, vpn3, vpn3, vpn2, vpn2, vpn1

Meaning, vpn3 has a 3-in-6 chance of being chosen.

If the nexthops have different costs (such as latency) and you want the lowest-cost one to always be prioritized, then you need to use 2 or 3 *separate* routes, each with one gateway and a different "metric" value. Then the route with the lowest metric (which means lowest cost) will always be used as long as BFD reports that it is up.

In BIRD, metric for static routes is set through the `igp_metric` attribute. For example, if vpn3 has lowest latency (must always be prioritized), but vpn2 and vpn1 are equal (keeping random selection between the two), you could use:

```
route 15.235.0.0/16
  via 10.13.0.1 % 'vpn3' bfd
  { igp_metric = 10; };

route 15.235.0.0/16
  via 10.12.0.1 % 'vpn2' bfd
  via 10.11.0.1 % 'vpn1' bfd
  { igp_metric = 20; };
```

Comment: Thx,now I now the weight is chance no priority.I already set the diffence cost in OSPF,check I added codes above.VPN3 is 10,VPN2 is 20,VPN1 is 30,but seems not working.

Comment: @YuChow: OSPF costs only work on routes that are received _through OSPF_, such as stubnets or external "imported" routes – configuring a local static route bypasses OSPF completely. For your setup to work as intended, you need the _remote_ gateways announce their own routes to the 15.235.0.0/16 network via OSPF, then your local gateway will automatically select the lowest-cost one.

Comment: I disabled remote gateway send and recive routes,only be a exit node .All static route all imported by local static routes table.

Comment: And the igp_metric only working one.The igp_metric = 10 not show up in `show route all`

Comment: What's the point of using OSPF then, if it doesn't handle any routes? Does `show bfd session` report 10.13.0.1 as up?

Comment: yes,all up.And if I set the 10 to 20 and remove the second route,only leave one,it show up.

Comment: igp_metric = 10 set won't show anythings.And two same route only show one route in `show route all`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I set this weight settings.250 times connections will go vpn3 248 times,that is enough.Temporary solution.LMAO

```
route 15.235.0.0/16
via 10.13.0.1 % 'vpn3' bfd weight 248
via 10.12.0.1 % 'vpn2' bfd weight 1
via 10.11.0.1 % 'vpn1' bfd weight 1;
```